# Solutions to linear SDE with many noise sources

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, stochastic-processes, differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

It is well known how to solve the linear stochastic ODEs with one source of noise
$$dX_t=(a(t)X_t+c(t))dt+(b(t)X_t+d(t))dW_t$$
See, for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Linear_SDE:_general_case .

I would like to know how solutions to SDEs with many noise sources, i.e., to
$$dX_t=(a(t)X_t+c(t))dt+\sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_i(t)X_t+d_i(t))dW^{(i)}_t,$$
do look like.

It wouldd be great if you could help me here! Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your SDE as following,
$$dX_t=X_t\Bigl[a(t)\,dt+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i(t)\,dW^{(i)}_t\Bigr]+\Bigl[c(t)\,dt+\sum_{i=1}^nd_i(t)dW_t^{(i)}\Bigr].
$$
Where $W=\{(W^{(1)}_t,\cdots, W^{(n)}_t)^{\top},t\ge 0\}$ is an n-dimensional continuous martingale. Let 
\begin{align}
Y_t&=\int_0^t a(s)\,ds+\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^tb_i(s)\,dW^{(i)}_s,\\
H_t&=\int_0^t c(s)\,ds+\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^td_i(s)dW_s^{(i)}.
\end{align}
Then
$$ dX_t=X_t\,dY_t+dH_t. \tag{1}$$ 
Accoding D. Revuz & M. Yor, *Continuous martingales & Brownian Motions*, 3rd edn(Springer, Berlin 1999), p.378, the solution of (1) is the following
$$ X_t=\mathscr{E}(Y)_t\Bigl[X_0+\int_0^t\mathscr{E}(Y)^{-1}_s(dH_s-d\langle H,Y \rangle_s)\Bigr].$$
where
\begin{gather} \mathscr{E}(Y)_t=\exp\Bigl[\int_0^ta(s)\,ds+\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^tb_i(s)\,dW^{(i)}_s
-\frac12\sum_{i,j=1}^n\int_0^t b_i(s)b_j(s)d\langle W^{(i)},W^{(j)}\rangle_s\Bigr],\\
\langle H,Y\rangle_t=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\int_0^tb_i(s)d_j(s)\,d\langle W^{(i)},W^{(j)}\rangle_s,
\end{gather}
and $\langle W^{(i)},W^{(j)}\rangle$ is the bracket(or covariation) process of $W^{(i)}$ and $W^{(j)}$(c.f. Revuz & Yor's book, p.125). If $W$ is continuous Gaussian process with $\mathsf{E}[W^{(i)}_t]=0$ and $\mathsf{E}[W^{(i)}_sW^{(j)}_t]=\sigma_{ij}(s\wedge t)$, then $\langle W^{(i)},W^{(j)}\rangle_t=\sigma_{ij}(t)$. If $W$ is components independent n-dimensional Brownian Motion, then $\langle W^{(i)},W^{(j)}\rangle_t=\delta_{ij}t$.

Comment: Many thanks for your input! Could you tell me what the scalar (like d<H,Y>) is supposed to mean?

Comment: Also, when n=1, do the equations come down to the ones like in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Linear_SDE:_general_case ?

Comment: @tobias Thank you for your replication. I already add the definition of W, <W,W>, and <H,Y>.

Comment: Okay, that looks much better. Could you write down a bit more on \sigma_{ij} then as well? That would be great! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are doing a great job! But with the current definition of \sigma_{ij} couldn't we dramatically simplify the solution by considerung in the sums ranging over i and j simultaneaously only those terms with i=j?

Comment: @tobias Thank you again for your help to improve the formulating. If it is not clear please let me know, I will do my best to improve it.

Comment: Well, yes I am quite new to the field, so I am cautious when it comes to simplify the formula. But, again, isn't it possible to simplify the formulas dramatically because of what I said beforehand?

Comment: @tobias If the components of W are independent (or orthogonal in local martingale), then $\langle W^{(i)},W^{(j)}\rangle =0, i\ne j$.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that we can simplify the sum terms that range over both i and j?

Comment: @tobias $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^na_{ij}$. What "simplify" do you want?

Comment: I mean that if the $W^{(i)}$ are independent then we have $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} = \sum_i a_{ii}$ in the sums from above. Would you agree?

Comment: @tobias Yes, you are right, if the components of $W$ are independent, then we have $\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}=\sum_{i}a_{ii}$.